# pod init command not running

Tags: cocoapods

When i run **`pod init`** command it showing me

```
git version 2.20.1
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper$ReflectiveAccess to method sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl.getFD()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper$ReflectiveAccess
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
RuntimeError: Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("")
                  git_version at /Users/maheshpandit/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:118
  verify_minimum_git_version! at /Users/maheshpandit/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:130
                          run at /Users/maheshpandit/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49
                       <main> at /Users/maheshpandit/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55
                         load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1007
                       (root) at /Users/maheshpandit/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.5.0/bin/pod:1
                         eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046
                       <main> at /Users/maheshpandit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.5.0/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:24
```

for command **`sudo gem install cocoapods`** shows me

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/Users/maheshpandit/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jopenssl.jar) to constructor java.security.cert.CertificateFactory(java.security.cert.CertificateFactorySpi,java.security.Provider,java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Successfully installed cocoapods-1.5.3
1 gem installed

not creating pod file ...
```

Comment: Is there some sort of SSL Inspection in your LAN network? (e.g. corporate firewall SSL inspection)

Comment: No don't have any SSL Inspection in LAN i guess there is problem of git version so i upgraded it to latest (2.20.1) but still it showing me same error failed to extract git version